# Adding Redux to an existing ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redux

I have a pretty traditional ASP.NET MVC application. I would like to start using a Redux store in the application. One obstacle that I am facing is that much of the initialization happens in JavaScript (initial state, reducers, etc.). I can trace a setup ReactJs and Redux application through the startup of Index.js. I have also seen multiple examples of using VS to create a React/Redux application but unfortunately for me this is a "black box" of setup using webpack that I don't want to add to this project. Just Redux. But I am not sure where in this existing application the initialization for Redux should be as that startup seems to be in files like Global.asax and obviously I cannot make JavaScript client calls there. How do I insert Redux into an existing ASP.NET MVC application?

Comment: Are you sure you even want/need Redux? If your web-application is not an SPA then you might be barking up the wrong tree...

Comment: Right now the state is handled (or not handled) via a spinkling of 'hidden' variables in the Razor views. I think Redux would be better than that.

Comment: How does your page currently work? Does it use `<form>`-based POST submissions or is it a mini-SPA?

Comment: <form> based POST in Razor. So it has @Html.BeginForm(...).

Comment: Using Redux is **not** a good idea then.

Comment: Is there a better state management solution? As I said currently the say that state is handled is to pass the "state" via a field in the model and inject that client-side via a hidden field. So if the hidden field is placed on a parent or otherwise not accessible to the form thinks break. Also there is not a concept of a "single source of truth".